# How can I create a nested ul items inside li to align side by side

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a "dropright" css but I'm unable to make the nested ul to behave well

this is my mark up

```css
    .container{
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
    }
    .container: first-child{
      left:0;
    margin-left:0px;
    }
    .ul-items{
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="ul-items">
    <li>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <ul class="ul-items">
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This comes out the way I want but, I can't set the margin of the first ul so as not to have the `100px` what  am I doing wrong?

here is the pen:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/ladypython247/pen/powEKqE)

**Edit**
I have solved this problem, now I have a nasty case of `<li>` with no content and setting border bottom exposes it.

** Edit **
[How I want it to dislay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSuer.png)

Comment: Can you pls show us your desired look ?

Comment: I have added that, I have solved the issue, but the problem I am having now is that the parent <li> holding the nested <ul> displays *absorbs?(pardon my grammar) any style I am applying to <li> there by adding extra space. you can see it here. https://codepen.io/ladypython247/pen/powEKqE

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your query, Flexbox is very useful for a responsive design and adjusting multiple components inside a `div` container. You just have to add a few more properties to have the configuration you wish for.

You can try using the three `<ul>` unordered lists under the parent container.

HTML:

```
 <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
     <div class="container">
       <ul class="ul-items">
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item one</li>
      </ul>
    <ul class="ul-items">
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
   </ul>
    <ul class="ul-items">
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
  *{
   margin:0;
   padding: 0;
  }

 .container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content:flex-start;
   align-items: center;
  }

.container:first-child{
   margin-left:40px;
  }


.ul-items{
   list-style: none;
   margin-right: 60px;
  }
```

Flexbox provides a lot of other options too like `justify-content: space-around` or `justify-content: space-evenly` etc. If you are more interested in learning about flexbox, you can use https://flexboxfroggy.com/ game to learn flexbox in a fun way. It's one of my favourites and fun way to learn Flexbox.